# Unable to Access Principal Entity When Fetching Dependent Entity First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to configure the inverse of a Many-to-one-relationship. It looks like this:
Dependent is DocumentationMail.

```cs
public class DocumentationMail : IJob
{
    public int DocumentationOrderId { get; set; }
    public virtual DocumentationOrder DocumentationOrder{ get; set; }
}
```

Principal is DocumentationOrder.

```cs
public class DocumentationOrder
{
    public int DocumentationOrderId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DocumentationMail> Mails { get; set; }
}
```

This pattern matches Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cdata-annotations-simple-key%2Csimple-keyhttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cdata-annotations-simple-key%2Csimple-key).

It works to get the DocumentationOrder and its dependents like this:

```cs
// _context is a working database context
_context.DocumentationOrders.First().Mails.First().DocumentationOrder;
```

Even though this is a duplication as it fetches the same `DocumentationOrder` twice it works just fine.

However when getting a `DocumentationMail` first I'm always getting `null` as value for the following:

```cs
_context.DocumentationMails.First() //This works fine
_context.DocumentationMails.First().DocumentationOrder; //This doesn't work
```

Steps I already tried:

- Ensuring that database records match according to the wanted relation.
- I fiddled around with manual configuration which didn't bring the wanted result.
- Narrowed the problem down to few line of code.

Is it even supported at EntityFramework to get first a dependent and then the principal? If not how can I fix this? If yes where exactly is this stated?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default EF Core does not load the navigation items.
You can use different approaches, they are all discussed here https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/ef/core/querying/related-data

I would reccomend to use lazy loading:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    => optionsBuilder
        .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
        .UseSqlServer(myConnectionString);
```

(needs nuget package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies)

Comment: Thank you. However this adds problems when serializing to JSON.

Comment: It is a know issue, you should Serialize DTO to JSON, not DB Models.
https://automapper.org/ this is the most used .net library for mapping DB Models to DTO

Answer (score 0):

Try with [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) using `Include()` & `ThenInclude()` for that. You code will be like below.

```
context.DocumentationOrders
    .Include(do => do.Mails)
        .ThenInclude(mail => mail.DocumentationOrder)
    .First()
    .Mails.First()
    .DocumentationOrder;
```

Comment: I'm getting a warning that Include is not defined on ``_context.Mails.First().Include(m => m.DocumentationOrder).First();``.

Comment: You have to use `Include` before `First()`. You can exact code which I have posted in answer.